# Hybrid Active Directory Setup

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

firstly I'm looking for advise to check to make sure I have this information correct.

We currently have an on-premise Active Directory that our office users use to login to their machines with.

We also have a Azure AD for Office 365 License that came with our Office 365 for Business subscriptions.

What I would like to be able to do is sync our local AD with our Azure AD (for Office 365) and allow our users to sign in through Azure rather than our local (as none of our users are at the office anymore due to Covid-19)

So, if I have this correct, it should just be the matter of setting up another machine at the office, installing Azure AD Connect, then synchronising the 2?

This also leaves the question of, how do I then get the users to sign in via the new method without them loosing their existing windows profiles? (all users are on Windows 10)

Bit of background as to why I want to do this:
We have a WSUS server that deals with windows updates at the office, problem being, no one is at the office so the Group Policy is incorrectly stating to get Windows Updates from our server, So what I want from this is to update our Group Policy to look at Microsoft's servers to do the Windows Updates rather than our local server.